# Unable to increment pointer

Tags: c, pointers

In the  code section , the stringData++ line does not seem to increment the pointer at all. Is there something i am missing?

```
bool WriteString(const char* stringData)
{
if(*stringData == '\0')
{
    return true;
}

/* Write a character at a time, only if transmitter is empty */
while (PLIB_USART_TransmitterIsEmpty(USART_ID_1))
{
    /* Send character */
    PLIB_USART_TransmitterByteSend(USART_ID_1, *stringData);

    /* Increment to address of next character */
    stringData++;

    if(*stringData == '\0')
    {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

Below is the default example code, which works

```
bool WriteString(void)
{
if(*appData.stringPointer == '\0')
{
    return true;
}

/* Write a character at a time, only if transmitter is empty */
while (PLIB_USART_TransmitterIsEmpty(USART_ID_2))
{
    /* Send character */
    PLIB_USART_TransmitterByteSend(USART_ID_2, *appData.stringPointer);

    /* Increment to address of next character */
    appData.stringPointer++;

    if(*appData.stringPointer == '\0')
    {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

Here "appData" is simply an instance of a struct that has a const char pointer in it .

Comment: Why do you think so? You need to be more concise as to what your problem is and how it is reproducible.

Comment: You are increamenting a const char !

Comment: @MuhammadFarrukhFaizy Code is not incrementing a `const char`.  Code is increment a `const char *`, which is fine.

Comment: Code is quitting the transmit buffer  once it is full, is that the intention?  Maybe that happens after the first character is sent.  I'd expect it  to re-try maybe `n` times or until too much time has elapsed.  Does the calling code check the result of `WriteString()`?  IOWs, how did you conclude "stringData++ line does not seem to increment the pointer"?

Comment: `stringData++;` *does* increment a pointer. Did you mean to ask why the caller's variable passed as the argument to `WriteString` does not get incremented?

Comment: @chux the output is the first character of the string literal pointed by stringdata and it's a forever loop . I tested it with various characters and it was always only the first character . Yes the intention is to exit after finding the end of the string literal .

Comment: I did not ask about the source being consumed, I asked about the output buffer being full.  Maybe it is full, at least for a little while after receiving just 1 character.

Comment: @chux oh sorry about that. The buffer empty condition was the default example code which worked. I have edited the original post .

Comment: @chux on further debugging, it seems that the pointer does increment but the UART transmitter buffer does not seem to empty for next character transmission. I don't understand as to why this might occur as I have not edited any of that section from the default working example :(

Comment: 1) `appData.stringPointer` may be invalid.  The calling code is not posted, so that is not discernible here. 2) `USART_ID_2` may not have been opened properly - again, that code is not shown. 3) The channel may simply lack `PLIB_USART_TransmitterEnable()`.  4) IOW, the problem is not here in this code.

Comment: @chux Thanks for the help. The code was fine . It was a hardware timing issue . The modified version was executed faster than the default example since it does not have to unwrap a struct reference as in the example. This caused a problem as the transmission buffer did not empty fast enough to service the new routine and hence the write_string function failed after the printing the first character.

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm the code is fine and does increment the pointer. I wrongly assumed that the problem was because of the pointer not being incremented. On further debugging it turned out to be a hardware timing issue. Please refer to comments above for details.

Answer (score -4):

It looks like you're trying to increment a string that you defined as constant, which means the string is stored in read-only memory.

You might try removing the const from the string parameter.

Comment: `const char* stringData` means `stringData` points to `const` data.  It does not mean the pointer `stringData` is `const`.

Comment: C does not have a string type. And that is a non-`const` pointer. For a `const` qualified pointer, OP would get a diagnostic message.